# reindenting and organizing Javascript on Sublime

Tags: javascript, user-interface, backbone.js, sublimetext, indentation

I'm writing a huge javascript file and I need a way not to re-ident the file but also show the file in "Nice" organized way. For example.

```
defaults : {
  campusTotal : 0,
  buildingTotal : 0,
}
```

I'm currently using emmet and auto-indent on save plugin in sublime.

Can anyone point me for some good practices to keep code organized for Javascript developers?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. For anyone who is looking for organizing javascript code:

```
http://jsbeautifier.org/
```